# How can I plot error bars for each tuning parameter?

Tags: r, r-caret

After training a model, I would like to get an understanding of the variance of the train RMSE.  One way to do this is to add error bars to a plot of tuning paramater versus cross validated error.

Can I add error bars to a `train` plot if my training method has a `trControl`?  DO I have to do this manually by first getting `model$results`?  Shown below is a minimal working example.  I train a model and would like to plot the error bars for each tuning parameter.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ElemStatLearn)
library(caret)


data(prostate)

dtrain = prostate %>% filter(train) %>% select(-train)
dtest = prostate %>% filter(!train) %>% select(-train)



cv = trainControl(method = 'cv', number = 10)

set.seed(0)
model = train(lpsa ~ .,
              data = dtrain,
              method = 'pcr',
              trControl = cv,
              tuneLength = 8)

#No Error bars even though 10-fold CV?
plot(model)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `model` object to manually plot the error bars:

the needed data is in `model$results`:

```
  ncomp      RMSE  Rsquared       MAE    RMSESD RsquaredSD     MAESD
1     1 1.0354695 0.3532009 0.8847237 0.3973763  0.2996081 0.3558122
2     2 1.0571604 0.3546154 0.8983677 0.4268048  0.2884902 0.3682752
3     3 1.0546954 0.3446711 0.8945127 0.4429895  0.3191984 0.4101867
4     4 0.8761915 0.5676269 0.7259782 0.2582520  0.1701669 0.2354457
5     5 0.8251083 0.6212784 0.6755912 0.2087671  0.1721623 0.1595105
6     6 0.7956971 0.6377419 0.6539849 0.1827476  0.1400881 0.1433317
7     7 0.7822073 0.6789155 0.6330582 0.1834283  0.1413476 0.1636086

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(model$results) +
  geom_line(aes(x = ncomp, y = RMSE)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = ncomp, y = RMSE)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = ncomp, ymin = RMSE - RMSESD, ymax = RMSE + RMSESD), width = 0.3)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

If more than one tuning parameters was used you could map the first parameter to the x axis, second to color, third and forth to a facet grid.